# How to assign result of table function to variable in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Assume I have the following function declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_org_branch(IN p_org_id organization.org_id%type,
                                            IN p_padding text)
    RETURNS table
            (
                object_id int,
                parent_id int,
                name      text
            )
```

Then I want to call `build_org_branch` with parameters and assign it to a variable inside of another function like this:

```
declare
  l_table record[]; --??????
begin
  l_table := build_org_branch(1, ' '); -- is it okay?
  if l_table is not null then
    -- do stuff with table rows
  end if;
end;
```

Or should I use some another approach to pass tables of rows?

Comment: Uh.  You would store the contents of a table valued function as a temp table, not as a variable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you mean creating temp table and saving results there, right?

Comment: . . Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support table's variables. If you can pass a some relational content, then a) you can use a temporary table or b) you can pass a array of composite values:

```
CREATE TYPE branch_type AS 
(
  object_id int,
  parent_id int,
  name      text
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_org_branch(IN p_org_id organization.org_id%type,
                                            IN p_padding text)
  RETURNS branch_type[] AS ...
```

and then you can write

```
declare
  l_table branch_type[];
begin
  l_table := build_org_branch(1, ' ');
  if l_table is not null then
    -- do stuff with table rows
  end if;
end;
```

This is array to array assignment. Table to array is possible too, but always it has to be static typed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_org_branch(IN p_org_id organization.org_id%type,
                                            IN p_padding text)
  RETURNS SETOF branch_type AS ...
```

and processing:

```
declare
  l_table branch_type[];
begin
  l_table := ARRAY(SELECT build_org_branch(1, ' '));
  if l_table is not null then
    -- do stuff with table rows
  end if;
end;
```

For smaller number of rows (to ten thousand) a arrays should be preferred. For high number of rows you should to use temp table.

Answer (score 2):

You have built a function that returns a table, so process the results that way.

```
do $$ 
declare 
  rec record;
begin
  for rec in (select * from build_org_branch(101, ''))
  loop 
      raise notice 'Returned Row: object_id=>%, name=>%, parent_id=>%'
                 , rec.object_id
                 , rec.name
                 , rec.parent_id ; 
      -- do stuff with table rows
   end loop;             
end;
$$;
```

I do not have your table, so I'll hard code some values but how they are populated is not the issue, but what you do afterward. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ae5ae6c4ba615d05094610aefbdee567).

Comment: I used your solution as I can't change function's spec but I marked Pavel's answer as a solution cuz I think his way is more appropriate in an abstract situation.

Comment: That's fine and thanks for the upvote. I agree @Pavel is a reasonnable  abstraction. But I'm a simply guy and development by simple rules. In this case "Use the simplest solution available. Abstract to reduce complexity, but you still have to deal with the abstraction."